# Mobile Navigation Help: Jquery .scroll()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm working on this site: http://www.toddoltmann.com

As you can see, the navigation icon (hamburger) changes colors based on the scroll position. This looks ok on desktop, however it does not work well on mobile. If you view it on a mobile device (where you use your finger to scroll), you'll see that that the color transition appears very delayed. How can I fix this so that when the top of the viewport reaches a particular section (on mobile) the nav icon changes colors smoothly, without having to scroll again to trigger the event?

```
 Here's my HTML:

<div class="open">
 <span class="cls"></span> 
 <span>
  <ul class="sub-menu ">
   <li> <a href="#audio-section">Music</a> </li>
   <li> <a href="#events-section">Events</a> </li>
   <li> <a href="#video-section">Videos</a> </li>
   <li> <a href="#contact-section">Contact</a> </li>
  </ul>
 </span> 
 <span class="cls"></span> 
</div>

<!-- First Container: Splash -->
<div class="container-fixed full-width splash">
</div>

<!-- Second Container: Audio Player -->
<div class="container-fixed" id="audio-section">
  <div class="row audio">
      <h1>MUSIC</h1>
      <div class="audio-player">
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Third Container: Youtube Media-->
 <div class="container-fixed" id="events-section">
  <div class="row events">
    <h1>EVENTS</h1>
    <div class="col-xs-5 events-left">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-7 events-right">
    <div class="box-right"></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Third Container: Youtube Media-->
<div class="container-fluid full-width" id="video-section">
  <div class="row video">

    <h1>VIDEOS</h1>

    <div class="featured-video">

    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-videos">

    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Fourth Container: Contact Form -->
<div class="container contact" id="contact-section">
  <h1>DROP ME A LINE</h1>
  <div class="row" >

  </div> 
</div>


Here's my jQuery:

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var iconPos = $('.open').offset().top + 10;
  var audPos = $('#audio-section').offset().top;
  var eventPos = $('.events').offset().top;
  var vidPos = $('#video-section').offset().top;
  var contactPos = $('#contact-section').offset().top;
  var navIcon = $('.open span');
    if (iconPos >= audPos && iconPos < eventPos) {
      navIcon.css('background-color', '#4e3446');
    } 
    else if (iconPos >= eventPos && iconPos < vidPos) {
      navIcon.css('background-color', '#e8dfd6');
    }
    else if (iconPos >= vidPos && iconPos < contactPos) {
      navIcon.css('background-color', '#4e3446');
    }
    else {
      navIcon.css('background-color', '#e8dfd6');
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks okay on my Nexus 5, what mobile device is giving you issues?

Comment: I'm using an iPhone 5